'best poster' and 'best talk' prizes - can we do better determining winners?
I am a new board member of a few small, local research and health societies.
We run a couple of events each year, often with poster and oral presentation prizes. One thing that I noticed as a judge in my specific environment is that these prizes are highly random. Basically, the most dominant judge will push their choice through to first place. In another example, I have witnessed a few prizes that went to horrible presentations, some that were so bad that I talked about their poor quality to my other senior colleagues and they completely agreed.
Is there a good way to determine winners? I don't really mind who wins the prize but rather I am sympathetic with those many presenters that don't win. What sticks often with them is that they weren't good enough and the winner seemed to clearly out-competed them, which is objectively not true. I had several students asking me for how they could improve and although I am providing feedback, I know it was 'not their fault'.
I thought about how we could improve things. One of my ideas was to determine the top presenters (say 2 per judge or so) and then decide the winner by lot. That way nobody knows if they were in the inner circle and luck with support a good talk but it's not necessarily 'the best'.
Just to re-emphasise this, I am talking about small societies with less than 100 members where almost everyone knows each other and most often also know about their work.
What do people think? Thanks for any input!

Create a simple rubric and make sure more than one judge evaluates each presentation and poster. Then tally up the scores.

I don't find clear in your question whether you call prizes "highly random" in the first place because there were many about equally good contributions (in which case I'm not sure much can be done), or because you think contributions that were clearly better didn't win the prize. If a "most dominant judge" pushes undeserving contributions to win, the problem may need very different treatment from a situation in which you don't have clear criteria and the like.

Or is the problem rather that you are worried about the overall quality and want to stimulate participants to do better by becoming more competitive? This issue is again different from the two potential problems mentioned above.

I don't know if this is within your power, but I would start by considering whether the prizes are a good thing in the first place. What purpose are they serving? Do they actually motivate people to produce better work?

If it were up to me, I would replace the word "best" with something else, since it's clearly not the case that there exists any "best" paper or talk, nor that this process could reliably pick it if there were. I'm not sure what I'd use but something like highlight, spotlight, or even just award.

Are you rewarding the presentation quality only, or the science that is being presented?  It's possible to present good science in a horrible way or vice versa.  Is it clear to jury members what they should look at?

Your random selection idea reminds me of what some funding agencies have started looking into (random selection between proposals beyond a threshold). It's a theoretically sound solution to the problem, but really bugs people on an emotional level. We don't love randomness, and it seems we prefer it to be hidden away behind a few obstructing layers than out in the open.

To follow up on @usul's suggestion of terminology, we've used "featured" instead of "best". Some awards shows use "favorite." Another: "starred" like in book reviews. "Judges' choice" would be explicit without implying any value judgement.

The obvious solution to "the most dominant judge will push their choice through to first place" is to not discuss among judges and just average their scores instead.

the most dominant judge will push their choice through to first place Maybe don't let that happen?

I don't know how this is done in other fields, but in math when we've done this with undergrad posters, often we have a whole group of judges for each poster, and then the top posters are determined by averages of those results. I've also encountered a setup where the top few (say something like 10%) all got recognition and then additional judging for those top 10% happened.
Doing a random selection as you suggest seems suboptimal. At that point, why not just recognize the top ones that would go into the lottery and not have the lottery at all? It isn't like there absolutely needs to be a single best.

Thanks for the suggestion!
We have some sponsors that want a picture with the winner(s). It's a great suggestion to acknowledge a larger group instead of picking out a few of them, I really like this idea.

Hmm, @Hydrazin In that case, make sure certainly that whatever you do, your sponsor is ok with the procedure.

The selection is always going to be somewhat subjective and, thereby, random, no matter what you do (like in the Olympic figure skating or gymnastics) but you can mitigate it somewhat by formalizing the procedure like there. First, select and agree upon a few reasonably well-defined evaluation categories (like "how clear is the presentation", "how interesting is the topic", "how much did the speaker engage the audience", or whatever else is of interest to you).
Then use some simple numeric scale for each. Don't try to evaluate by the score from 0 to 100: you'll break your head over deciding whether you should give 46 or 47 and end up in a hospital with a severe mental trauma; do some scale with few values that you can easily explain in words instead. For instance, when I grade my student quizzes, one of the scales I'm using is 4 for a full impeccable solution, 3 for a solution with minor (in my opinion) inaccuracies, 1 for a clear attempt to move in the right direction without much success, and 0 for everything else (including 5 pages of accurate computations that led nowhere as far as the task in the problem was concerned). There is no grade of 2.
Then just let each judge fill out the score sheet for each presentation he/she attended. Agree on the function that determines the overall score based on these sheets (it doesn't need to be additive, but it should be well-defined, made publicly available, and be simple enough to determine and verify the final score without a supercomputer or a huge reference table in Excel; it should also take into account the possibility that some judges may miss some presentations, if that is a likely event). Then just collect the sheets, compute the scores, arrange the candidates in the score order and decide where you want to make the cutoffs for the first, the second, etc. prize totally ignoring anybody's opinions on how inaccurate the other judges might be in their scoring and ruthlessly suppressing any such conversations before the winners have been announced. Then announce the prizes and give each contestant, winning or not, a copy of his/her evaluations (without the judge names) just like we are given the student evaluations when teaching.
That sounds simple in theory, but still requires some amount of preparatory work, self-discipline, and mutual respect, so if you want to set up something like that for an upcoming competition start early. It is not a panacea, but it will add a lot of transparency and credibility to the selection process in addition to clearly indicating to each competitor the jury opinions about their strong and weak points, not just his/her overall ranking.
Just my two cents :-)

The first paragraph could have used an appearance of the word "rubric". That's what the paragraph proposes.

You could take a leaf from many subjective sports scoring methods and eliminate the top and bottom scores as a way of mitigating prejudice (i.e. a judge who loves or hates the presenter rather than the presentation)

Frame challenge: It's better not to have prizes for best talk/poster.
The OP and others have pointed out some negatives of these prizes: the process for choosing them is flawed and opaque, people who don't get the prize end up feeling bad, and knowledgeable colleages are frustrated by the outcomes. I want to add another serious negative of prizes in general, which is that they are heavily skewed towards people in majority groups (white cis males in STEM, for example) due to biases against people in equity-seeking groups.
The question seems to posed under the assumption that there must be so many positives to giving these prizes that it outweighs these acknowledged negatives. Personally, I don't think that's the case.
(The feedback mechanism fedja proposed in their answer, if carried out respectfully, could be very valuable to the younger academics giving talks/posters. Perhaps that could be done for its own sake instead of in service to prizes.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Try to minimize the random choice to the minimum. It is demotivating in the best to compare yourself as a looser to a winner whose presentation/poster with feeling that it was worse than mine. You start wondering what was the winning feature I missed to spot?
It will look burreaucratical and overcomplicated, especially for non-technical fields, but good system and respectful commitee solves most of the issues.

As a comittee agree on equal vote and pick one to decide possible conflicts (draw, special cases, etc.)
As a commitee agree on what attributes you are to assess the
contributions on. Define how the performance will be evaluated and summed. Define weights to each "topic". Bonus points for
disclosing for the contenders.
Print evaluation sheets for every contender and every referee. Submit the evaluations anonymously.
Sum up the scores and make the list. Resolve the conflicts and draws.
Write down comments and ideas from the referees about the process and iterate to improve the process.

There is a huge drawback of this system - you need to keep the same measures throughout all the sessions. I'd strongly recommend the very first presentation/poster being awarded 50/100 by default in every category as a benchmark.
In case you are concerned about conflict of interest (referee is tied with at least one contender) you can sum up average scores among referees and referee can submit marks with "In Conflict" that will be discarded.

You can also divide the prize in several smaller prizes. Award top 5 or top 10.

What if the best presentation is by far the best/worst?

I suppose you meant "the first" is far best/worst. I think this level of outclassing/failure is quite improbable. If the first will be the extreme, you are still left with 0-50 or 50-100 scale, which is still quite fine scale.

Oops, yes, I did.

Frame challenge: Rate the presentation of the work, not the incomparable content/impact.
While determining the best talk/poster may be an very complicated task, especially in life/health sciences where expertise from half a dozen disciplines is required to assess correctness. Yet, instead of presenting prices for the best poster/talk, make the prices only about how stuff was presented - detached from the quality of the content. This may also decrease variability, if done correctly, as accessibility of information may be assessed with specifically prepared questionnaire. Furthermore, science communication is a very important topic which deserves praise, if done properly, hence prices may be fitting.
Disclaimer: This suggestion is biased from my own experiences in life/health sciences. I have seen talks winning best talk which presented correlations of 4 datapoints and an obvious outlier, or t-tests between 2 states with 3 datapoints each - fundamental flaws most undergrads can identify. Awarding such talks/posters with a best work sends a clear message to, especially younger folks, in the audience.
In sum, thereby the winning talks do not have to be the best, most impactful, or most relevant ones, but can simply be the best presented ones.

So, an "artful" but nonsense talk is best? Seems odd. Professor Irwin Corey would win every time.

Well, in life/health sciences, jurors are often asked to judge poster's in fields they know very little about, for example jurors with a background in genetics judging posters on pharmacology.
With that level of divergence in terms of expertise, why not level the playing field and judge which poster/talk managed to get its points across, especially when considering there are dedicated prices towards science communication?
